# python arbitrary slicing using a function

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a function that can make an abitrary slice of a list eg:

```
def slice(arr, a, b, step):
        return arr[a:b:step]
```

The problem is, how to handle if a user wants the slice arr[5:] or arr[:5] in a nice way?

Comment: But there is already a function that can do this.  It's `list.__getitem__`.

Comment: additionally, there is already the [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) builtin

Answer (score 2):

Omitting a value in a slice is equivalent to using `None`, so I may suggest this function signature:

```
def slice_(arr, start=None, stop=None, step=None):
    return arr[start:stop:step]
```

Recommend not to use the name `slice` for your function, because it shadows [the built-in class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice).

Note:  You don't need to define your own function for this functionality.  A more Pythonic way of slicing an object with dynamic input would be with using getitem directly:

```
arr[slice(a,b,step)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This already exists in the standard library

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.getitem(arr, slice(start, stop, step))
```

Comment: –1 You have *very* old version of Python!

Comment: And it doesn't work with a step, and it hooks into a deprecated part of the 2.7 object model.